# Bar code scanner using user media

Tags: javascript, html, barcode, barcode-scanner

I developing an web application that is gonna be responsive so it can also be used on phones/tablets. This is the 2.0 version, the previous version has an web application and an Android app, on the Android app there is this feature that read an bar code from products and query for it on the database..

I am looking for a HTML5 + JavaScript plugin to read barcodes that is efficient and easy to use, can you suggest some?

Comment: software recommendations are off topic.

Comment: I've implemented something like this before and I used the Zebra Xing tools and put a web service in front of it.  so I can send text to the service and get an image back and on the other side you can post the raw data from an image / photo and have the service parse it and send back the underlying message

Comment: You could use `<input type="file" capture="camera" accept="image/*" />` and feed it to a JS-based decoder (like https://serratus.github.io/quaggaJS/ ). But the user experience will not be as good as with a native plugin where the app closes the camera UI as soon as it detects an decodes a barcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use Phonegap, I can highly recommend this https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner
Great D